# Replace with unknown character

Tags: json, replace

I am correcting a json-Array. I want to replace a few errors.

For Example: in `"index" : NumberInt(8),` i want to cut off `NumberInt(*)` without the number where the * is, in order to make the json-file valid.

How can i do that? didn't find anything on google. it's quite hard to define this question.

**Example**

Before:

> "index" : NumberInt(8),

(Some way of changing the JSON)

After:

> "index" : 8,

**Edit:**

after the marked answer i could figure out my specific case by myself.

I solved my provlem using the "Back-References" ($1, $2, etc)

Example, which i used for my case:

> press cmd+R -> replace function
>
> insert in Search-String: `NumberInt\(+(\d)\)` insert in
>   Replace-String: `$1`
>
> what happens: it searches for "NumberInt()" and replaces it
>   with the , referenced by the $1-symbol.

Thanks for your help! i learned a lot

Comment: Could you show a before and after of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes. I know my formulation is quite difficult to understand.
`"index" : NumberInt(8),`   ->   `"index" : "8",`


Is this even possible? My JSON file is over 153959 characters.. would be a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: are you ok with `groovy`?

Comment: never heard about it. I'm working with ruby on rails at the moment

Comment: You should tag your question with the language you are using. Also, how did you get `"index" : NumberInt(8),` in the first place, since it's not valid JSON?

Comment: I think it doesnt matter. I just want to replace the strings in RubyMine via the Replace Function.

Comment: The JSON was generated from a MongoDB via MongoChef, hence the weird fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  there might be a bit missing from the question but I'm going to make some assumptions and hope thats what you were going for.

I'm going to assume that `NumberInt(8)` is a string (if it's not you can operate on the object and pull out the first argument and set that as the value)

If we are looking to pull out what's in the parens we could use a basic Regexp (`()` around what we want as a second element):

```
v = "NumberInt(8)"
v.match(/NumberInt\((\d)\)/)
=> Array [ "NumberInt(8)", "8" ]
```

Should be able to `parseInt()` the second element and override the previous value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it helped me alot.

Comment: i marked this as answer, event it's missing a part.

I solved my provlem using the "Back-References" ($1, $2, etc)

Example, which i used for my case:

press cmd+R -> replace function

insert in Search-String: `NumberInt\(+(\d)\)`
insert in Replace-String: `$1`

what happens: it searches for "NumberInt(<any int>)"
and replaces it with the <any int>, referenced by the $1-symbol.

Thanks for your help! i learned a lot, will put this into question-Edit..